# ValueError: Only call `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` with named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...) error

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

The error is ValueError:

> Only call `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` with named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...).

The code is https://github.com/drvladb/stackoverflow/blob/master/code.py.

It is run in Python 3.5.2 *with* tensorflow 1.8 and numpy 1.13.3. I have tried using different versions of python and tensorflow and on a docker and anaconda but no avail.

Can I please get some help with fixing it?

Comment: Please consider rewriting your question in the form of a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You are passing variables (as "plain" arguments), it is expecting keyword arguments `keyword=value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only line making reference to `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` in your code is [line 206](https://github.com/drvladb/stackoverflow/blob/master/code.py#L206), so I will assume it's where you got your error.

The error message is kind of explicit, you need to use **named arguments** (or **keywords arguments**) with the method `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

So, I guess you want something like:

```
softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=self.one_hot_y, logits=self.logits)
```